# What's the simplest way to read data from a text file into a 1xN integer in MatLab

Tags: matlab, file-io

What's the simplest way to read datas from a text file into a 1xN integer in MatLab?

I'm writing the data into a text file from a Java program, which means it is highly flexible how the text file could look like. These data are to be plotted (pdf or cdf).

The file could be quite large, millions of integers. It shouldn't matter I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a text file (not a binary file), you can probably just use the [LOAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) command:

```
data = load('file.txt','-ascii');  %# Load the data
data = data(:).';                 %'# Format the data into a row vector
```

I assume your data file could have one value per row **or** one long row with values separated by spaces, so the `(:).'` operation (a [colon reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html) plus a [transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html)) ensures that no matter which one it is you will get a 1-by-N result for `data`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that cdfplot will work for either 1-by-N or N-by-1. Thus the line 1 of your code will do the job good enough. Thank you very much.